# Adding an RTE to salesforce text areas

Tags: textarea, salesforce, rte

Does anyone know if there's a way to add an RTE to textarea fields within salesforce? I'm fairly new to the platform but i haven't been able to find any useful documentation on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using VisualForce, you can use the [inputTextArea](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/index_Left.htm#StartTopic=Content/pages_compref_inputTextarea.htm#kanchor665) tag to edit/save rich text.  Set the "richText" attribute to true.

Comment: just been recommended this by someone else also, looking into it now. is this my only option?

Comment: The only other way I can think of would be to use an s-Control, however SalesForce is phasing out s-Controls in favor of VisualForce, so I would still recommend going that route.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to the  component, there's also an example of integrating the open source FckEditor component into Visualforce here:

http://blog.sforce.com/sforce/2009/05/a-rich-editor-component-for-visualforce.html